# jQuery Plugin Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).slider is not a function

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I made a plugin for my webpage. It works as a standalone HTML file fine. But when I use it as wp plugin a jQuery Plugin I need (Bootstrap Slider https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) throws this error above.

I included jquery and this boostrap-slider plugin like that:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'child_jquery','cdn URl');
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-slider',  'CDN Url');
```

And call the plugin in my code so:

```
jQuery("#m1,#m2,#m3,#m4,#m5,#m6,#m7,#m8,#m9,#m10,#m11,#m12").slider({
    reversed : true,
    tooltip: 'show'
});
```

This call is within a document ready function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

My suspicion, after the plugin is loaded a further jquery is enqued.
So in the source code I have (simplified):

```
jquery.js
bootstrap-slider.js
jquery.js (an old one from wp)
```

I tried to deregister it and right after that enqueue it again. But if I do that the plugin still doesn't work and another plugin throws this error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
 function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-slider',  'CDN Url', array('jquery'), false, null);
}
```

What I am doing is deregistering the WP jQuery script. Then I'll add a new jQuery script with the CDN. I will enqueue this script and then enqueue your bootstrap slider script with jquery as a dependency. This means jQuery will be loaded BEFORE Bootstrap Slider.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I already found the deregister and register but never with the dependency factor. My slider still not works but a least, no error anymore :) I can work from there. Thanks!

Comment: Probably you need to also initialize the slider with some other Javascript. You need to use this _after_ the jquery en bootstraplider js files. You can enqueue another script file with that piece of code and require both jquery and bootstrap-slider with `array('jquery', `bootstrap-slider `)`.

Comment: Yeah ... Little embarrassing but I just forgot to enqueue the CSS of the plugin ;-)

Comment: Ah bugger, those little silly bugs are the most Time consuming one's

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my BxSlider Plugin which is now fixed (see excerpt below from my wcslider.php file) using your method, thank you very much.

```
function wcslider_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bxslider', WCSLIDER_PATH . '/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css');
    if(wp_script_is('jquery', 'enqueued')) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
        wp_enqueue_script('bxsliderjs', WCSLIDER_PATH . '/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'), false, null);
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }   wp_enqueue_script('bxsliderjs', WCSLIDER_PATH . '/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'), false, null);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcslider_scripts');
```